# How to list all unmerged changes in Git?

Tags: git, branch

Creating a branch for various topics, and not regularly deleting them when I don't need them any more, I have now ended up with about 50 branches.

I tried deleting branches but some of them have unmerged changes.

What I want is the ability to see exactly what changes are there in any branch on my repo that are not in `master`. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 308, accepted):

To list branches with commits not merged into master:

```
git branch --no-merged master
```

To include remote branches:

```
git branch -a --no-merged master
```

To list the relevant commits:

```
git cherry -v master <branch>
```

Comment: "git branch --no-merged master" does not show remote branches - clues to see those too?

Comment: Add the `-a` flag to include remote branches.

Comment: If it's giving u error, try to replace `master` by `origin` as upstream.

Comment: note that branches merged by squash & merge will still show differences, even if there are none.

Comment: Adding `-a` parameter will show local and remote branches and with `-r` will show only remote branches.

Comment: What do the + and - signs before the commit hash mean?

Comment: @RobertNiestroj (+) Means it needs to be applied to the other branch. (-) Means it can be dropped (because it is already there). See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry: "Here, we see that the commits A and C (marked with -) can be dropped from your topic branch when you rebase it on top of origin/master, while the commit B (marked with +) still needs to be kept so that it will be sent to be applied to origin/master."

Answer (score 41):

I came across this question when I was trying to remember the syntax of...

```
git log <branch> --not master --stat
```

This will show commits to <branch> that have not been merged to master. The --stat will include the files that were changed with the commits. You can also use this to compare any two branches by replacing master with a different branch name.

Answer (score 7):

This question is already well answered, but there is one more answer I think is worth documenting:

List all commits on any branch not already merged with master:

```
git log --all --not master
```

or, equivalently:

```
git log --all ^master
```

The `--all` picks up all branches, so you don't have to list them, then `--not master` or `^master` removes master from the selection.

Comment: + some formatting for a more elegant output
`git log --all --not master  --graph --pretty=format:"%C(auto)%h%d%Creset %C(cyan)(%ci)%Creset %C(green)%cn <%ce>%Creset %s" --name-status --date=short`

Answer (score 0):

For the PowerShell folk a little combination of what has been said above. If needed, replace `master` with `main`. Test by pasting into your shell.

```
$notMergedList = (git branch --no-merged master) -replace " ", ""
ForEach($branchItem in $notMergedList) {
  write-host "~~> branch: $branchItem" -Foregroundcolor DarkCyan
  git cherry -v master $branchItem }
```

Answer (score -8):

It is quite easy to get an overview of your branches with `gitk`.

Comment: Not if you have >20 branches