# How to know whether a commit merged from another branch with gitlab api?

Tags: git, gitlab

How to know whether a commit merged from another branch with gitlab api?
Or with git command?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Git exposes this information with [git log](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) command. You are able to filter this further by only looking for specifically merge commits with **--merges**

```
    git log --merges
```

Try the above command with the branch you are interested in. You should be able to see the history of where the changes were merged from.

Comment: thanks,but seems not solve my problem.
for example:I have 3 commits on branch a,then I checkout to branch b,and merge from a.As I think those 3 commits belong to branch a.I don't know whether am i misunderstanding?

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2707110/2442239) by [@Jefromi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/119963/jefromi) shows two ways that might be what you are looking for:

Find branches the commit is on:

```
git branch --contains <commit>
```

Find a subsequent merge commit:

```
git log --merges <commit>..
```

[And this other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3602022/2442239) one by [@gawi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/138830/gawi) shows a way to list branches not yet merged in a specific branch:

List branches with commits not merged into *master*:

```
git branch --no-merged master
```