# Is there any way to find which commits from branch A have not been merged on branch B (having it as a nightly report)?

Tags: git, azure-devops, devops

I'll try to be as short as possible. We are using GIT and Azure DevOps. We have a master and a develop branch of the current version of the app we are working on. But since we have to offer support and maintenance on older versions we do have other branches like: 8.0, 7.5 ... etc.

For each release we create a Hotfix and a Release branch. That means, fixing a bug on hotfix will further imply the fix to be validated by a QA and then cherry-picked on release. The problem we have here is that there might be cases when some commits haven't been merged or cherry-picked to release (because someone have forgot or maybe some conflicts appeared).

We would like to solve that problem in a more automated way (because we are more than 70 people working on the project).

**An idea would be somehow to generate a report using a batch or maybe some other tools, that would show us which commits had not been merged/cherry-picked from hotfix to release.**

Any other ideas are welcome!

Thank you in advance

---

Since I got a notification from Stackoverflow that my question might be a duplicated of [Git : List all unmerged changes in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3600728/git-list-all-unmerged-changes-in-git) I will try to justify that it's not.

I tried

```
git log origin/80-hotfix --not origin/80-release --cherry --stat
```

And that actually contains also commits that had been already merged to 80-release (not all of them).

Also

```
git cherry origin/80-release origin/80-hotfix
```

doesn't work for me.

Maybe it's the wrong way I use those, but for sure after making several checks I have found pull-request that has been completed cherry-picking commits to 80-release. I am interested only in those that are NOT (cherry-picked and merged).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git : List all unmerged changes in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3600728/git-list-all-unmerged-changes-in-git)

Answer (score 0):

With `git log` you can use two periods to show a difference. For example, on master branch

```
git log ..feature/NewLogos
```

will give you all the commits `feature/NewLogos` has that master does not. You can use the other tools git log has to make this more suited to a report.