# Git: List of branches that its commits exist on master branch of specific author

Tags: git, branch

My current scenario is that I have a `master` branch from which I have many branches created from it and some of them I have merged them to the master.

What I am trying to get is the list of branches which I have not merged to the `master` and I am the author.

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a look to this thread : [How to list all unmerged changes in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3600728/how-to-list-all-unmerged-changes-in-git).

There are several ways, one of them is the following:

`git log --all --not master --author=<name or email>`

Comment: As mentioned in the linked question, I tried the command `git branch --no-merged master` and it gave me the result which I asked. However, the command `git log --all --not master --author=<name or email>` gave me a full list of commits and not a list of branches.